# How to get inner html tag from outer html?

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I am trying to learn how to scrape images from net.
there is one page where I want to scrape an image from a div.
The id of the div is 'hotels'.
and the class of the 'img' is 'lazy'.
In order to get the image from the image tag of the division and displaying it via echo, I am applying the following code. But its not displaying.

```
$e1=$html->find('div[id=hotels]');
$e2=$e2->find('img[class=lazy]');
echo $e2;
exit;
```

can anybody tellme is that the right way to call the inner tag of a division?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo:

```
$e2=$e2->find('img[class=lazy]');
     ^---- this should be $e1
```

Comment: it does not work. I tired.